# NestJS Interceptor - how to get response status code and body after response is end

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

In interceptor i can get response status by `context.getArgByIndex(1)`. This code logs a 403 status code as i wanted. But this code `context.getArgByIndex(1).statusCode` return to me status 201. I throw out status 403 from the service.

Interceptor code

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LogsService } from './logs.service';

@Injectable()
export class LogsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor( private readonly logService: LogsService ) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    
    
    this.logService.constructorData(context)

    console.log(context.getArgByIndex(0)) --- **This code logs the correct status**
    console.log(context.getArgByIndex(0).statusCode) --- **This code logs status 201**

    return next.handle()    
  }
}
```

Service code that throws an error for the test

```
async findAll(): Promise<PodsDto[]> {
     throw new ForbiddenException()
     return this.PodsRepository.find()
}
```

Comment: @shemm11 / shem - [Dont upload screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/979052), and don't create a secondary accounts to edit your question. Instead add the actual code, using the account you asked the question from.

Comment: You'll also need to share your backend code, as that is where the issue is. In it's current state, it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: @Lissy93 - Added a description. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a not good option, but it works.

Interceptor code

```
@Injectable()
export class LogsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor( private readonly yourService: yourService) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();

    response.on('close', ()=>{
      this.yourService.yourFunction(context)
    })

    return next.handle()
  }
}
```

**V2** If u need to read response body

```
@Injectable()
export class ActionLogsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor( private readonly yourService: yourService) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();

    return next
    .handle()
    .pipe(
      tap((responseBody) =>  this.yourService.yourFunction(context, responseBody)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Why do you think it is not a good solution?

Comment: @c_froehlich, because this method cant read to response body