# Execute Code After Completing Response In NestJS

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

**Objectives**: To run some code after the response is completely processed and sent out successfully.

Based on the docs I tried something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${Date.now()} Before...`);
    const now = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(tap(() => console.log(`${Date.now()} After... ${Date.now() - now}ms`)));
  }
}
```

and `app` is configured like this:

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs: true,
    rawBody: true,
  });
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggingInterceptor());
  app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
```

However the problem is that `"After..."` is logged before `"request completed"` HTTP log (`nestjs-pino` with `pino-http`). I'm assuming that means the code was executed before the response was sent out. (Is that right?)

**Other attempts**
Using [onFinished](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished):

```js
  app.use((req: IncomingMessage, res: OutgoingMessage, next: any) => {
    next();
    onFinished(res, function (err, res) {
      console.log(`${Date.now()} onFinished with req ${req.url}`);
      console.log(`${Date.now()} onFinished with error ${err}`);
    });
  });
```

But the outcome is the same. Moreover, apart from some issue with error handling, it's applied to every HTTP requests even outgoing ones (which is not what I want). Most probably this is not how it should be used.

I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72285929/2194119):

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    response.on("close", () => 
      console.log(`${Date.now()} After...`));

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Which seems to work, i.e. it does log `After...` after `request completed`. However the author posted it with a comment: *Maybe a not good option*. I'm a newbie in NestJS and not sure why it's not a good option.
What is the right way to execute some custom code after the response is sent out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
 constructor(--someurdeps--) {}

 async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
  return next
  .handle()
  .pipe(tap(()=>{
     const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
     res.on('finish', ()=>{
      --ur logic after response is sent--
     });
   });
 }
}
```

so exception will not break ur app